# Unicode errors with Jenkins & nosetests from a Python 3 Anaconda env

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, nose, anaconda

I am trying to set up Jenkins to use a Python 3 environment made with Anaconda. Unfortunately my tests are failing with Unicode errors that I think should only be present when run with Python 2.

When run from the console I get no errors and all tests pass (using Python 3). I have set up the following build config for Jenkins which appears to enable the Python 3 environment properly:

```
source /Users/ihuston/anaconda/bin/activate py34
python --version
nosetests --version
nosetests --with-xunit --all-modules --traverse-namespace
```

Python reports a 3.4 version and the nosetests version is the same as installed in the py34 Anaconda env.

The errors from nosetests also seem to be in the Python 3 version of the libraries:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test suite for <class 'test_mymodule.LoadDataFormat'>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 210, in run
self.setUp()
  File "/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 293, in setUp
    self.setupContext(ancestor)
  File "/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 316, in setupContext
    try_run(context, names)
  File "/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 470, in try_run
    return func()
  File "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myproject/workspace/tests/test_mymodule.py", line 88, in setUpClass
    f.write(cls.header + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error with `write()` does not appear when the module or the tests are run from the console by hand using Python 3.4. It does appear by hand if run with Python 2.7 as expected.

`which nosetests` shows the right executables in the Anaconda env:

```
+ which nosetests
/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/bin/nosetests
+ which python
/Users/ihuston/anaconda/envs/py34/bin/python
```

Is nosetests picking up a different version of Python from within Jenkins somehow?